# While loop in Game of Nim not stopping

Tags: while-loop

I have Java homework where I need to program the Game of Nim. Essentially, this is a two player game  where the players each remove stones from 3 piles. The last person to remove a stone is the winner. I wrote a while loop so that the program will stop asking the player to make a move when all the stones have no stones. However, it does not stop. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome!");
        System.out.println("This is the game of Nim.");

        System.out.println("[1] Pile 1:    9");
        System.out.println("[2] Pile 2:    9");
        System.out.println("[3] Pile 3:    9");

        int stones1 = 9;// These variables will be used
        int stones2 = 9;// in order to subtract a number
        int stones3 = 9;// of stones from the pile.

        int tStones = stones1 + stones2 + stones3;  

        while (tStones > 0){
            System.out.println("From which pile would you like to take?");
            String aMove1 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("How many stones would you like to take?");
            String bMove1 = input.nextLine();
            int naMove1= Integer.parseInt(aMove1);
            int nbMove1= Integer.parseInt(bMove1);

            if (naMove1 == 1){            //This stack of code will
                stones1 = stones1 - nbMove1;   
            }                              
            if (naMove1 == 2){            // subtract stones based on the
                stones2 = stones2 - nbMove1;    
            }
            if (naMove1 == 3){            // pile input and stone input. 
                stones3 = stones3 - nbMove1;
            }

            if (stones1 < 0){
                if (naMove1 == 1){
                    System.out.println("That move is invalid.");
                    System.out.println("But nothing happened!");
                    stones1 = 0;
                    naMove1 = 0;
                    nbMove1 = 0; 
                }
            }
            if (stones2 < 0){
                if (naMove1 == 2){
                    System.out.println("That move is invalid.");
                    System.out.println("But nothing happened!");
                    stones2 = 0;
                    naMove1 = 0;
                    nbMove1 = 0;
                }
            }
            if (stones3 < 0){
                if (naMove1 == 3){
                        System.out.println("That move is invalid.");
                        System.out.println("But nothing happened!"); //splash 
                        stones3 = 0;
                        naMove1 = 0;
                        nbMove1 = 0;
                }   
            }

            System.out.println("Taking " + nbMove1 + " stones from stack " + naMove1);

            System.out.println("[1] Pile 1:   " + stones1);  //This stack will display 
            System.out.println("[2] Pile 2:   " + stones2);  //the stone count for 
            System.out.println("[3] Pile 3:   " + stones3);  //each pile after the first move. 

        }
        System.out.println("You lose!");
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't update tStones in your while loop, but thats the break condition.

Comment: So what do you suggest, Gnietschow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating `tStones` in the body of the while loop

try updating it as :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nim {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome!");
System.out.println("This is the game of Nim.");

System.out.println("[1] Pile 1:    9");
System.out.println("[2] Pile 2:    9");
System.out.println("[3] Pile 3:    9");

int stones1 = 9;// These variables will be used
int stones2 = 9;// in order to subtract a number
int stones3 = 9;// of stones from the pile.

int tStones = stones1 + stones2 + stones3;  

while (tStones > 0){
    System.out.println("From which pile would you like to take?");
    String aMove1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How many stones would you like to take?");
    String bMove1 = input.nextLine();
    int naMove1= Integer.parseInt(aMove1);
    int nbMove1= Integer.parseInt(bMove1);

    if (naMove1 == 1){            //This stack of code will
        stones1 = stones1 - nbMove1;   
    }                              
    if (naMove1 == 2){            // subtract stones based on the
        stones2 = stones2 - nbMove1;    
    }
    if (naMove1 == 3){            // pile input and stone input. 
        stones3 = stones3 - nbMove1;
    }

    if (stones1 < 0){
        if (naMove1 == 1){
            System.out.println("That move is invalid.");
            System.out.println("But nothing happened!");
            stones1 = 0;
            naMove1 = 0;
            nbMove1 = 0; 
        }
    }
    if (stones2 < 0){
        if (naMove1 == 2){
            System.out.println("That move is invalid.");
            System.out.println("But nothing happened!");
            stones2 = 0;
            naMove1 = 0;
            nbMove1 = 0;
        }
    }
    if (stones3 < 0){
        if (naMove1 == 3){
                System.out.println("That move is invalid.");
                System.out.println("But nothing happened!"); //splash 
                stones3 = 0;
                naMove1 = 0;
                nbMove1 = 0;
        }   
    }

// Updating here
    tStones = stones1 + stones2 + stones3;

    System.out.println("Taking " + nbMove1 + " stones from stack " + naMove1);

    System.out.println("[1] Pile 1:   " + stones1);  //This stack will display 
    System.out.println("[2] Pile 2:   " + stones2);  //the stone count for 
    System.out.println("[3] Pile 3:   " + stones3);  //each pile after the first move. 

}
System.out.println("You lose!");
}
}
```

Comment: @noah.chun It's Working , Now the loop will be finished whenever your piles are all zeros , If your goal is not this then check the logic of the program again